# "When I was a student, I would live in a small apartment with three friends" Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: used-to

In my English book I found this question:
Is this sentence grammatically correct?

- When I was a student, I would live in a small apartment with three friends.

My answer was that is correct but turns out that is not.
I'm confused why is not correct. In this case "would" can be replaced by "used to".

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

While "would" and "used to" have the same meaning, "would" can only be used with *action verbs*, while "used to" can be used with both *action verbs* and *state verbs*.

In your example, "live" is a *state verb*, so you cannot use "would" with it.

> When I was a student, I **used to** live in a small apartment with three friends

is OK.

Comment: Another possibility is "when I was a student I lived in a small apartment".